# python3: TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types. Got (<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>)

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following codes:

```
def get_my_metrics(self, input_id:int) -> AttrDict[(str,str), float]:
     :
    return my_dict
```

I also tried to use Dict:

```
def get_my_metrics(self, input_id:int) -> Dict[(str,str), float]:
     :
    return my_dict
```

But both cases I got the following errors:

```
TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types. Got (<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>).
```

Am I not allowed to use `tuple` in `Dict` and `AttrDict` ? Or what did I do wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's because types for your dictionary is wrongly specified.

I'm not sure what do you want to achieve but if the returned dict have for keys one string and for value one float:

```
def get_my_metrics(self, input_id:int) -> Dict[str, float]:
    return {'foo': 42.42}
```

If keys are a tuple of two strings (as your question suggest) :

```
def get_my_metrics(self, input_id:int) -> Dict[Tuple[str, str], float]:
    return {('foo','foo'): 42.42}
```

(Don't forget the `from typing import Tuple`)

Additional remark:
There is a syntax error in your methods descriptions, yous should not put another colon before the return. Do:

```
def foo():
    return
```

instead of:

```
def bar():
    :
    return
```

Answer (score 1):

duck-duck send me here, because I had the same error-message.

Which you also will get, if you mistype and write `Dict[str: Any]`. Notice the colon, which comes naturally in `dict`s, but this a `Dict`. So typing wants a comma.

Sam Ting!